# Is "meet" an appropriate abbreviation for "meeting"?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, abbreviations

I would like to start a project that has the word "meeting" in its title. Could "meet" replace "meeting", or would this have an adverse effect? Would this be using "meet" properly?

Answer (score 0):

***​[Meet](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/meet)***  as a noun refers to sports events, if you are referring to business or social gatherings you should use "***[meeting](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/meeting?q=meeting%20)***":

> - (us) a sports event:
>   *a track/swim meet*
>   the first meet of the season
>   ​
> - (uk) an occasion when people go fox hunting

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: "Meet" is also the term used by many non-athletic clubs, particularly of the nerdish variety.  (Though "meetup" has lately become the more idiomatic term in this arena.)

Answer (score 0):

Not in a business setting, which I assume you mean by the fact that you're talking about a project. Sometimes meetings are called meets, but this is usually done to be cheeky. And such a meet is never a formal meeting, but a less formal social encounter or gathering (e.g. "meet and greet"). (Or, as JOSH points out, a sporting event.) In a business setting, one would never say "I'm headed to my 9 AM status meet."